# node-mssql transaction not committing

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to run queries again my database using node-mssql. Everything works perfect. But when I try to execute queries within a transaction, transaction gets committed but tables remain empty. Can someone check whats wrong with the code:

```
var transaction = new sql.Transaction(/* [connection] */);
    transaction.begin(function(err) {
        // ... error checks 
         console.log("[Info]","Begin Transaction.");
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(-1)
        }
        var request = new sql.Request(transaction);
        var transactionFailed = false;

        var request = new sql.Request(transaction);
        //request.multiple = true;
        request.verbose = true;
        request.query(upsertQuery);
        console.log("[Info]",request)
        request.on('error', function(err) {
            transactionFailed = true;
            console.log(['Error'],err.toString())

        });
        request.on('done', function(errs) {
            if(transactionFailed) {
                transaction.rollback(function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        process.exit(-1)
                    }
                    else {
                        process.exit(-1)
                    }

                }); 
            }
            else {
                transaction.commit(function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        process.exit(-1)

                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Transaction Committed!")
                    } 
                });
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you get any error or just empty table ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with my sql query. the above code works fine